# representing curl command in java

Tags: java, curl, upload, authorization

what is the Java equivalent of the following curl command:

```
curl -u <username>:<password> -F "access=@svnaccess.txt" https://svn.xxx-xxx.de/upload.cgi
```

i try to update the access rules of a svn repository by uploading a .txt file to this url.

any help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it.

The @-argument indicates the upload of a file, rather than its contents.

Changed code:

```
MultipartEntityBuilder builder = MultipartEntityBuilder.create();
builder.addBinaryBody("access", new File("./svnaccess.txt"));
HttpEntity entity = builder.build();
httppost.setEntity(entity);
```

Thanks for pointing me in the right direction!

Answer (score 0):

From your curl command you are using

- `-u` to use basic auth with the provided username and password
- `-F` which uses http verb `post`
- `@` to load the contents of the file

The Java equivalent is to use [HttpClient](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/index.html). However most examples are out of date with the current version. So as of 4.4.1 ...

Authentication is simplify a case of building `HttpClients` with a `CredentialsProvider`

```
CredentialsProvider credsProvider = new BasicCredentialsProvider();
credsProvider.setCredentials(
    new AuthScope(server, (https ? 443:80)),
    new UsernamePasswordCredentials("username", "password")
);
CloseableHttpClient httpclient = HttpClients
    .custom()
    .setDefaultCredentialsProvider(credsProvider)
    .build();
```

To reproduce your use of -F to upload a file you will want to add something that implements `org.apache.http.NameValuePair` and you can then use UrlEncodedFormEntity with your file you want to upload.

```
List<NameValuePair> formparams = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();

formparams.add(new FileNameValuePair("access", new File("./svnaccess.txt")));
UrlEncodedFormEntity entity = new UrlEncodedFormEntity(formparams, Consts.UTF_8);
httppost.setEntity(entity)
```

---

### Runable Example

#### Example.java

```
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;
import java.util.*;

import org.apache.http.*;
import org.apache.http.auth.*;
import org.apache.http.client.*;
import org.apache.http.client.entity.UrlEncodedFormEntity;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.*;
import org.apache.http.client.utils.*;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.*;


public class Example {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        String server = "svn.xxx-xxx.de";
        String path = "/upload.cgi";
        Boolean https = true;

        curl(server, path, https);
    }

    private static void curl(String server, String path, Boolean https)
            throws URISyntaxException, IOException, ClientProtocolException {
        CredentialsProvider credsProvider = new BasicCredentialsProvider();
        credsProvider.setCredentials(
            new AuthScope(server, (https ? 443:80)),
            new UsernamePasswordCredentials("username", "password")
        );

        CloseableHttpClient httpclient = HttpClients
            .custom()
            .setDefaultCredentialsProvider(credsProvider)
            .build();
        URI uri = new URIBuilder()
            .setScheme(https ? "https":"http")
            .setHost(server)
            .setPath(path)
            .build();

        try {
            HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(uri);
            List<NameValuePair> formparams = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();

            formparams.add(new FileNameValuePair("access", new File("./svnaccess.txt")));
            UrlEncodedFormEntity entity = new UrlEncodedFormEntity(formparams, Consts.UTF_8);
            httppost.setEntity(entity);
            CloseableHttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
            System.out.println(httppost.getRequestLine());
            try {
                System.out.println("----------------------------------------");
                System.out.println(response.getStatusLine());
            } finally {
                response.close();
            }
        } finally {
            httpclient.close();
        }
    }


}
```

#### FileNameValuePair.java

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;

public class FileNameValuePair implements org.apache.http.NameValuePair
{
    private String name;
    private File file;

    public FileNameValuePair(String name, File file)
    {
        this.name = name;
        this.file = file;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public String getValue() {
        String everything = "";
        try(BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file))) {
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            String line = br.readLine();

            while (line != null) {
                sb.append(line);
                sb.append(System.lineSeparator());
                line = br.readLine();
            }
            everything = sb.toString();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return everything;
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! I get the idea behind your code, but unfortunately it doesn't quite work.

Information:   POST https://svn.xxx-xxx.de/upload.cgi HTTP/1.1
Information:   ----------------------------------------
Information:   HTTP/1.1 200 OK

The content of the svnaccess.txt file does not appear in the admin console of the svn repository (http://imgur.com/4euC8AK , example only, actual content is much much more).

Comment: Does ``FileNameValuePair.getValue()`` return the contents of the file? Try ``FileNameValuePair fnvp = new FileNameValuePair("access", new File("./svnaccess.txt")); System.out.println(fnvp.getValue());`` and see if any value is printed

Comment: Yes, println(getValue()) prints the expected content of the file.